# неправильная работа jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

День добрый! Подскажите в чём может быть проблема. Поменял системный блок и начались проблемы. у меня подключена библиотека `jquery.json.js`. Теперь при загрузке JSON файлов он не распарсивает автоматически файлы. При сохранении текстовых документов на компьютер через PHP, он экранирует все ". На других компьютерах всё работает нормально. Работаю на JS и через denver.

Comment: Как вы отдаёте JSON сервером? На других компьютерах тоже Denwer стоит?

Comment: Denwer уже безнадежно устарел. Используйте osPanel

Answer (score 0):

Сделал. Проблема заключалась в Denwer, помогла переустановка Denwer.